# sencha touch - datepickerfield do not show dates before current date

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How do i force the sencha datepicker field to show dates only from current date. And not show the previous dates?

Thanks

Comment: This question is really unclear. What are you trying to do? Display the current date and then what..?

Comment: Am sorry Rob.. I meant show dates .. Basically the datepicker field should not show previous dates. Example, yearFrom and yearTo controls the years to be displayed. I want something similar for dates. Thanks

Comment: Well think about it, it's not possible. If i would disable the month january and februari (because it's march) and then proceed to select next year, january and februari should be enabled again. You will have to sort this either programmatically or validate the date on submit.

Comment: you can set min year...

Comment: {
    xtype : 'datepickerfield',
    label : 'date',
    picker : {
        yearFrom : 2013
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rob said, its not possible because  If i would disable the month january and februari (because it's march) and then proceed to select next year, january and februari should be enabled again. If i have to still achieve it, i have to solve it either programmatically or by validation.